# FileUpload control in aspx.net not allowing file read

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, file-permissions

I'm trying to read an uploaded file to the server using a FileUpload control, however, I'm gettting the following error:

> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via `<identity impersonate="true"/>`, the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user

I investigated and it seems that the folder do not have the permissions of the Network service account, so I add it but the problem is still there. Here is the code of my FileUpload control:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" style="top: 164px; left: 12px;       position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 281px" />
```

And here is the code that I'm using to save the file in my server:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\folder\\autoTrack.xlsx");
    StatusLabel.Text = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
    {
        this.readFile("C:\\folder\\autoTrack.xlsx"); //this is where the program crash due to lack of permissions!
    }
    else 
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Select a file to start the process!";
    }

}
```

The ACL of the c:\folder folder have the network service with Full control permissions, and inheritance is enabled to propagate to child objects.

Also I read that using a domain account in the Identity tab of the application pool can resolve the problem, but if I change the identity from the predefined Network service to my domain user, I got "Service unavailable" when trying to reach my application.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I was able to find out the issue. You have to set the DCOM properties for the network service in the server. The link below describes how to do it:

http://community.spiceworks.com/education/projects/Setting_The_Default_DCOM_Properties_And_Security

After setting up this I stopped receiving the access errorrs.

Answer (score 0):

First, try giving Everyone permission in the folder to see if it works. If it does, then is just a matter of finding the correct user to grant the right permission. If you are running on IIS you should grant permission to the application pool user as explained here -> http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Thanks for replying, I added the Everyone group with full permissions but still getting the same result. I configured the application pool identity to authenticate with network service with no success (I'm running IIS 6.0 BTW, the tutorial that you gave me applies for IIS 7.0)